# Facebook account sends link for video chat in chat pop up automatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Sometimes my Facebook account sends link for video chat in chat pop up window by its own to any of my online friends. Sometime it sends links like "this guy looks like u" and something like that.

All this things are done automatically. I come to know only if that receiver reports me for that thing.

How can I stop all these things?

Answer (score 2):

From what you are saying, there are two possibilities:

- you have some malware on your computer
- you gave permissions to a rogue/spammy Facebook app

To understand in which of the situations you are, first thing to do is to check if this happens when you are on a different machine. If it doesn't, then it's malware (on your computer). If it happens, you might want to check your Facebook apps and remove the "strange" ones.

Edit: it could also be a rogue browser plugin, so check that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had this behavior.
I might have misunderstood your question, but it sounds like malware. Are you using Windows by any chance?

Could you please try on another PC (or on a Live CD like [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html)) and if the same behavior does not happen, that means you must cleanup your PC.